# Consolidate an XSL when with multiple tests upon the same xpath

Tags: xml, xslt

Considering:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="/XmlOutput/CurrentController/conCategory/aField/contentId!=8 
        and /XmlOutput/CurrentController/conCategory/aField/contentId!=16 
        and /XmlOutput/CurrentController/conCategory/aField/contentId!=17 
        and /XmlOutput/CurrentController/conCategory/aField/contentId!=18 
        and /XmlOutput/CurrentController/conCategory/aField/contentId!=19 
        and /XmlOutput/CurrentController/conCategory/aField/contentId!=20 
        and /XmlOutput/CurrentController/conCategory/aField/contentId!=21">
        <xsl:call-template name="foo" />
    </when>
</choose>
```

How might I group these into a more concise test?

Comment: This expression probably does not do what you want it to. `=` and `!=` comparisons in XPath are existentially quantified so you're saying "if there is at least one `contentId` that is not 8, and at least one `contentId` that is not 16, ..." - a test that will always be true if there are at least two different `contentId`s.  You probably want `not(.... = 8)` instead of `.... != 8`.

Comment: As for how to make it more concise, `<xsl:variable name="cid" select="/XmlOutput/CurrentController/conCategory/aField/contentId"/>` and then you can test for `not($cid=8 or $cid=16 or .....)`.

Comment: In my case, the 'and's do appear to be what I need. I'm trying to mimic a sort of switch statement, where the template is only called on pages without those specified ids (there is only ever one id per page). The 'and's do seem to work to that end, but I'd like to shorten up the expression. I think your variable approach makes sense there... trying that now.

Comment: Fair enough, if there is always _exactly one_ node selected by `/XmlOutput/CurrentController/conCategory/aField/contentId` then `$cid != 8` and `not($cid = 8)` mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked well for me in tidying up the expression:

```
<xsl:variable name="cid" select="/XmlOutput/CurrentController/conCategory/aField/contentId"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$cid!=8 
        and $cid!=16 
        and $cid!=17 
        and $cid!=18 
        and $cid!=19 
        and $cid!=20 
        and $cid!=21">
        <xsl:call-template name="foo" />
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using XSLT 2.0, you could use a sequence:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="/XmlOutput/CurrentController/
        conCategory/aField/not(contentId = (8,16 to 21))">
        <xsl:call-template name="foo"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!--tbd-->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

In this example, the test is on all `contentId` elements in `/XmlOutput/CurrentController/conCategory/aField`. Also, `contentId` has to be a number.

Comment: Now that's pretty awesome.